# Geolocation Redirect to certain webpage

Tags: html, geolocation

I'm at a loss here. I've found all the HTML5 geolocation items to detect user location. But what I need to do is redirect them to the nearest location webpage. So if they are in/near San Antonio, maybe within a certain range (50 miles), they will be sent to the `/san-antonio/` page on the site. Same would go for other locations around the USA. And if they do no have geolocation permissions turned on, they get directed to the generic `/locations/` page.

I've found this basic code for getting the position:

```
   <script>
var x=document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation()
  {
  if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
  else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
  }
function showPosition(position)
  {
  x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude; 
  }
</script>
```

Where to go from here is a gray area. I thought this would be easy and easy google search, but i've come up with nothing.

Any help would be awesome since I just spent 5 hours trying to figure it out and have come up with nothing.

**EDIT:*** After searching our entire server for the word geolocation, I just found this in an old client theme, but i tested it and it doesn't give me the correct location. I don't know if it has something to do w/the where.yahoo api which isn't functional anymore. In the header.php file there is:

```
if (geo_position_js.init()) {
  geo_position_js.getCurrentPosition(success, null);
}
function lookup_location() {
  geo_position_js.getCurrentPosition(success, show_map_error);
}
function success(loc) {
  url='http://www.websiteexample.com/location/?long='+loc.coords.longitude+'&lat='+loc.coords.latitude;
  location.href=url;
}
function show_map_error() {
}
```

Then in the functions.php there is this:

```
function calc_distance($point1, $point2) {
$radius      = 3958;      // Earth's radius (miles)
$deg_per_rad = 57.29578;  // Number of degrees/radian (for conversion)

$distance = ($radius * pi() * sqrt(
            ($point1['lat'] - $point2['lat'])
            * ($point1['lat'] - $point2['lat'])
            + cos($point1['lat'] / $deg_per_rad)  // Convert these to
            * cos($point2['lat'] / $deg_per_rad)  // radians for cos()
            * ($point1['long'] - $point2['long'])
            * ($point1['long'] - $point2['long'])
    ) / 180);

return $distance;  // Returned using the units used for $radius.
}
function get_longlat($address) {

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?appid=8gkElW6o&q='.urlencode($address));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$loc = simplexml_load_string($content)->Result;
$geo['lat']     = (string)$loc->latitude;
$geo['long']    = (string)$loc->longitude;

return $geo;
}
function redirect_to_nearest($clientlong, $clientlat) {

$clientgeo['long'] = $clientlong;
$clientgeo['lat'] = $clientlat;

$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'location' ) );
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

    $custom     = get_post_custom();
    $slug       = basename(get_permalink());
    $location[$slug]['permalink']       = get_permalink();
    $location[$slug]['address']         = $custom[google_maps_address][0];
    $location[$slug]['geo']             = get_longlat($location[$slug][address]);
    $location[$slug]['distance']        = calc_distance($clientgeo, $location[$slug]['geo']);

endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();

usort($location,"cmp");

return $location[0]['permalink'];
}
function cmp($a, $b) {

if ($a['distance'] == $b['distance']) { return 0; }
return ($a['distance'] < $b['distance']) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Then in the actual custom post type archive page there is this:

```
if(isset($_GET[long]) && isset($_GET[lat])) {
  $redirectto = redirect_to_nearest($_GET[long], $_GET[lat]);}
if(isset($redirectto) && preg_match("/http:\/\/www.websiteexample.com\/location\/.*/i", $redirectto)) {
header( "HTTP/1.1 303 See Other" ); 
header( "Location: $redirectto" );
```

}

I thought I'd had struck gold. But I was wrong  :-/

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. (copied from flag dialog)

Comment: So where is your database of cities/areas and their co-ordinates?

Comment: I'm assuming I don't have one? It's a wordpress site and I do have custom fields setup w/the longitude and latitude for the actual locations (there are only 4). I've seen the "MaxMind" database, not sure if that is something I would need to hook in.

Comment: If you have co-ordinates then use the [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula).

Comment: @robertc I just edited my code above with what i thought was the holy grail after search 200,000 files on our server. But it doesn't work.